# how can i customize order processing flow in nopcommerce 2.4/5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

i think it's too reduplicate , eg. is it possible to combine shipment and payment page , how difficult

is it ?

and can i just not use nopcommerce nop.web project , instead of my own Web project .

thanks !!!

updated: i mean not the default CheckoutOnePage , but mixing payment info with shipment info in one form

[image]

Answer (score 0):

nopCommerce is a fully customizable shopping cart; therefore, it is possible to combine the functionality of the shipment and payment pages.

How difficult is it?  That depends on your skill level.  It is an open source system and if you are a seasoned developer, you will nail it pretty easily.  If you aren't, you will not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your first question is concerned, I will say Yes it is possible to combine both pages, difficulty level depends on your skill set, but as a tip I will suggest you to check OnePageCheckout file located in Nop.Web\Views\Checkout 
It will help you in understanding the one page checkout mechanism and from there you can have idea how to fulfill your requirements.

For your second question, I will recommend you to use the nop.web project instead of yours, as if you use your own web project, than you will be investing a lot of time trying to do a thing that is already done and it will be tough to put your front end on back end of Nop.

Comment: sorry , maybe i didn't make it clear, not the OnePageCheckout, i mean filling Payment and Shipment info in one form .

Comment: and for second question , if designers have already designed all static HTML Pages , what is the best way to integrate nop with these pages ? thanks